# What is more effective in my case read by char (getc) or read by chunks (fgets)

Tags: c, performance, compiler-construction

My team at the university is programming a compiler in the C language. The compiler gets source code in the sublanguage of Goland and outputs byte code in the language that is similar to assembler. My question is – what approach is more effective, read source file char by char (getc) and depending on the current character change the state of FSM or read by chunks (fgets) and call auxiliary functions that contain FSMs to process single lexemes and output tokens?

Comment: You can easily set up an experiment for profiling this. You know better than any one of us of your specifics.

Comment: Do whatever is easier for you. In the context of writing a compiler, this decision is almost irrelevant. (FWIW, the original lex tokeniser used fgetc and the most commonly-used modern varient -- flex -- does its own buffering. Lex was much simpler. Flex is somewhat faster, but the difference is not significant in any complicated application.) If you can use a parser-generator tool, do so: it's a lot easier than writing your own FSM.

Comment: How about using GNU Flex or a similar program to build your lexical analysis stage for you instead of implementing it manually?  That way you get the benefit of a few decades of many programmers' time and experience in tackling the kind of problem you are asking about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger we are implementing a simple compiler within the course "Formal Languages and Compilers" in order to deeply understand all the details... so we can't use flex..

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: *read source file char by char (getc)*  Just remember that `[f]getc()` return an `int` - **not** a `char`.  If you stuff the returned value into a `char`, you won't be able to reliably detect `EOF`, or you'll detect a false `EOF`.

Comment: Whether you use `getc` or `fgetc`, you will (almost certainly) end up making the exact same number of reads (unless you are seeking all over the place), so page caches, disk IO, etc. will be totally irrelevant.   Implement what is easier.  Worry about trivial optimizations later.  This will almost certainly be a trivial (or probably negligible) optimization.

Comment: When he said "effective" I didn't think he meant "which has better performance?" - I thought he meant "which would make writing, debugging, documenting and maintaining easier?"  The answer probably depends on the Goland input language and whether whitespace is significant or not.

Comment: I think it depends on the language and its parsing rules. If you can produce valid parser tokens one character at a time without lookahead then use getc / getchar. For performance it hardly matters since the C library will be buffering the reads, unless you intentionally turn that buffering off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My team at the university is programming a compiler in the C language.

> What is more effective in my case read by char (getc) or read by chunks (fgets)

## In practice, it should not matter much.

Since the CPU is a lot faster than most disks, including SSD ones. And because of the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

Write your application, debug it, enable optimizations in your compiler (the one compiling your C code), then benchmark it. It is operating system and compiler specific.

On Linux, read documentations of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), [gprof(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gprof.1.html), [time(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html), [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html), [fopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html), [fflush(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html), [setvbuf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html), [fgetc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html), [fgets(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html), [getline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), [readline(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html), [time(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

If you happen to *use* [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), study its source code for inspiration,  and read the documentation of its [internals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/), and [invoke](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) it as `gcc -O2 -ftime-report  -ftime-report-details`; you'll discover that most of the time spent by a compiler is on [optimizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler), not on parsing.

You should consider metaprogramming approaches: use (or develop) for your compiler project programs generating C programs (inspired by [ANTLR](https://antlr.org/), [GNU bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Bison), [iburg](https://drhanson.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/documents/iburg.pdf), [SWIG](http://swig.org/), [RPCGEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPCGEN), etc...). Observe that GCC has a dozen of specialized [domain specific languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and corresponding code generators. Consider perhaps using [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) (or, in november 2020, [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/)) for such purposes.

**Most of your compiler should transform internal compiler representations** (e.g. simplified [abstract syntax trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), perhaps inspired by [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html), and you might consider using [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) if your teacher allows it)

#### On other operating systems and compilers, read their documentation.

Read of course the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools).